# using .intValue wrong?

Tags: java, arrays, integer, quicksort

So I've been trying to get the average of my integer array and my method down there isn't doing the greatest because I'm trying to fit an object reference into a primitive.. I tried using intValue and I think im using it wrong.. any ideas?

```
       //Variation 3 - Choose Mean as pivot
   private static int getMeanIndexAsPivotIndex(Comparable comparableArray[],int leftIndex, int rightIndex) {
          int sum = 0;
          int add = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < comparableArray.length; i++) {
        add = comparableArray[i].intValue();
        sum +=  add;
    }
    return sum / comparableArray.length;
}
```

Here is where I made my array

```
     //Random Array
 Integer[] unsortedArray = new Integer[8];
   for (int i = 0; i < unsortedArray.length; i++) {
       unsortedArray[i] = randomRange(0,1000);
   }


    QuickSort.java:157: error: cannot find symbol
        add = comparableArray[i].intValue();
                                ^
  symbol:   method intValue(int)
  location: interface Comparable
Note: QuickSort.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
1 error
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your signature `comparableArray` is of type `Comparable[]` instead of an `Integer[]`, this type does not have an `.intValue()` method.

Changing the method signature to use `Integer[]` should solve the problem.

Comment: Yep that worked! But now I have an ArrayIndexOutofBound exception -_-. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

Elaborating on @EricBouwers's answer.

The class `Integer` extends the class `Number` and implements the `Comparable` interface, i.e., the class declaration is

```
public final class Integer extends Number implements Comparable<Integer>
```

Implementing `Comparable` in a class means that the class provides a means (a method) to compare between different instances of the class using the `compareTo` method. This method is (the only one) *declared* in the `Comparable` interface and *implemented* in the classes implementing the interface.

This has nothing to do with the `intValue` method of class `Integer`. This method is declared and implemented in class `Number` and overridden by its subclass `Integer`. It *unboxes* an `Integer` object (instance of the class) to an `int` primitive.

As for your code, you are trying to call `intValue` for the `Comparable` interface, but is is undefined there, hence the `error: cannot find symbol` (symbol being the method you tried to invoke). You are confused because `Integer` "includes" `Comparable`, but it doesn't work the other way around.

You *can* write this:

```
Comparable<Integer>[] arr = new Integer[]{1,2,3};
```

but then `arr` will *not* be able to invoke `intValue` because it is of type `Comparable` and not `Integer`. It will be able to invoke `compareTo`.

You *cannot* write this:

```
Integer[] arr = new Comparable<Integer>[]{1,2,3};
```

although in theory you might think that you will be able to invoke both `intValue` and `compareTo` on `arr`.

What you need to do is this:

```
Integer[] arr = new Integer[]{1,2,3};
```

and then you can invoke both `intValue` and `compareTo` on `arr`.